# join three subquery result sets with null in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have following three subquery result sets, 
Result set 1:

### Id1 col1

1. V1
2. V2
3. V3

Result set 2:

### Id2  col2

1. V1
2. V2

Result set 3:

### Id3 col3

1. V1
2. V2
3. V3

If i use join result set will be

### Id1 col1 id2 col2 id3 col3

1. V1.  1.  V1.  1.  V1
2. V2.  2.  V2.  2.  V2
3. V3.  2.  V2.  3.  V3

Instead i want

### Id1 col1 id2 col2 id3 col3

1. V1.  1.  V1.  1.  V1
2. V2.  2.  V2.  2.  V2
3. V3.  2.  Null  3.  V3

Note : resultset row count will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

use `left join` instead

```
select T1.id1, T1.col1, T2.id2, T2.col2, T3.id3, T3.col3
from Table1 T1
left join Table2 T2
on T1.id1 = T2.id2
left join Table3 T3
on T1.id1 = T3.id3
```

Comment: Resultset row count will be dynamic. So left join will bot work out for all conditions

Comment: @RJ. , i didn't get it , can you explain with some example